# Not able to take footer out of the container

Tags: html, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I am using Constellation Theme wordpress and i am unable to get the footer out of the body

even though i place the code out of the body it was considering it as code inside the body how can one solve this kind of problem

site the problem exists is http://design3web.in/law-firm/

Comment: You can't, because the green border container is the `body` of a page. And you can't display any element outside the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because the **green border container** is the `body` of a page. And you can't display any HTML element outside the body. You need to tweak your markup to achieve this.

Note: Your whole HTML structure is buggy. Try to make it as according to **[w3c Standards](http://www.w3.org/standards/)**

**EDITED:**

**A Quick Tip:**

Add a wrapper `<div>` after `<body>` and apply all classes of **body** i.e. `home page page-id-23 page-template-default` on wrapper like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="home page page-id-23 page-template-default">
```

Also apply some css rules of body on wrapper css as given below:

```
#wrapper {
    padding: 14px 48px 64px;
    width: 1122px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 10px solid #3C8A3D;
    border-radius: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
}
```

And keep the rest css rules in body indeed.

And Then give your **footer** `<div>` a **css rule** `position:absolute;` and place it outside the **wrapper** `<div>` accordingly.

Comment: actually it is wordpress theme can u tell me how to tweak the markup

Answer (score 0):

Its is due to padding on your body tag

```
body {
padding: 14px 36px 64px;
width: 698px;
margin:20px auto;
font-size:1.4em
```

}

make some adjustment with the padding, i feel the structure is completely wrong, you should have used some wrapper and applied css on that wrapper instead of body tag.You need to take out all the css from body tag and use a wrapper and apply the same css, after that your footer will come out from that container.